# How to replace min and max value row in 2-d array python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

i have an 2-d array(matrix) 3x3 like
[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]]
and i need to replace 2 rows where is max and min value so its looks like:
[[7, 8, 9],[4, 5, 6],[1, 2, 3]]

```
from random import randint
def array():
    column = int(input())
    row = int(input())
    arr = [[randint(1, 100) for i in range(column)] for y in range(row)]
    print(arr)
array()
```

Comment: do you mean swap the min and max elements?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki i need to swap exactly rows, where elements are like i have 
[[52, 10, 25], [41, 20, 58], [64, 42, 21]]
and result :
[[64, 42, 21],[41, 20, 58],[52, 10, 25]]

Answer (score 0):

Using Numpy, apply `min` and `max` to find smallest and largest number, then specify their locations with `argmin`, `argmax`. Finally swap the rows.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 999, size=(10,10))

# find the row indices of min and max
imin = np.argmin(np.min(a,axis=1)) 
imax = np.argmax(np.max(a,axis=1)) 

# swap the rows
a[[imin,imax]] = a[[imax,imin]]
```